# Has many through doesn't persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a question about the Has Many Through relationship.

I have 3 models : Artist, Skill, and Mastery

skill.rb

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :masteries
  has_many :artists, through: :masteries
end
```

mastery.rb

```
class Mastery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

artist.rb

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :masteries
  has_many :skills, through: :masteries
end
```

Everytime I try to attach a skill to an Artist, using `artist.skills << skill`, a mastery is created, but the artist_id is nil. Same thing the other way around. `skill.artists << artist` gives me a Mastery with a nil skill_id.

Does this mean that I have to execute both every time ? Or did I miss something ?

Comment: it seems that skill isnt saved yet...

Comment: What version of ActiveRecord are you using?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I'm using the console to do so, with skill = Skill.last and artist = Artist.last ( I made sure both exist)

Comment: @Rashmirathi 4.2.0

Comment: Can you try in the console to call `artist.save` to ensure its saving after you add the association.

Comment: Hmmm, this is weird, it seems to work within the application, but not in the console. If I find anything I'll post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, here's why it failed : it appears that you cannot set it in rails console under certain unclear circumstances. However, if you got the same model setup as me, using the `model.attributes << attribute` syntax will work just fine. Obviously, if you need to create a fake relationship in your rails console, all you have to do is create a new `Mastery`, and set its `creator_id` and `skill_id` accordingly, then save it.